# Connect to Oracle DB by SSL usign IBM Java

Tags: java, oracle, ssl

I have an oracle database with tcps enabled. I created java class to make a simple query.

First of all I create the certificate and import it in 2 machines. One of the using oracle java, and the other one using ibm java....

So the problem is: I can connect and run the query using eclipse with oracle java.

But when I tried to run the same with ibm java I have the following error:

> java.sql. SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX
>   path building failed: java.security .cert.CertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:752)    at
>   oracle.jdbc. driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:662)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)

I used exactly the same certificated imported in both cacerts files.

Have you any clue about that???

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried with JKS files instead of a wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you used `keytool` to create the certificates. If so, use the "oracle java keytool" on one machine and "ibm java keytool" on the other machine.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias your_hostname -keystore your.keystore -storepass your_password -keypass your_password -validity 3650 -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=your_hostname"
keytool -exportcert -alias your_hostname -keystore your.keystore -storepass your_password -rfc -file oracle_or_ibm.crt
```

Install the two ([oracle|ibm].crt) generated certificates in Oracle database server/wallet. Might also help if you configure the database server with `SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE`. Then import the database certificate on the two client machines.

```
keytool -importcert -keystore your.keystore -storepass your_password -noprompt -file database-certificate.crt -alias database_alias
```

To check the keystore: `keytool -list -keystore your.keystore -storepass your_password`

Your Java code might look something like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class OracleJdbcTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))",
            "username", "password")) {

            System.out.println("Java JDBC Oracle Example");
            System.out.println("Connected to Oracle database!");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failure.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Run it like so:

```
java -cp ojdbc7.jar:. -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=your.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=your_password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=your.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your_password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Doracle.net.ssl_version=1.2 OracleJdbcTest
```

To debug, add the property: `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Might also need to play around with the TLS version (e.g. `-Doracle.net.ssl_version=1.1`)